# JPA in OSGI env - keep entity managers in sync

Tags: jpa, osgi

I have an osgi equinox env looking to utilize eclipselink jpa for entity persistence.  I'm unclear on a few things.  First, when\where\how many entity managers should be created for our solution?  Second, how do I keep these entity managers in sync if more than 1?

I have a parent entity with a bi directional 1..N relationship with a child entity. Parents can exist without children, and children can exist without parents.
I have a parent service that allows me to edit/add/remove/...  parent entities.
I have a child service that allows me to edit/create/remove/addToParent/removeFromParent/... child entities.

```
To handle the bi directional associations-
Add child to parent:
Parent p = em.getReference(Parent.class, parentId);
p.addChild(child);
beginTransaction();
persist(child);
commitTransaction();


Remove child from parent:
beginTransaction();
Parent p = child.getParent();
p.removeChild(child);
commitTransaction();
```

Right now, I have it that each service bundle looking to persist an entity is creating an EntityManager on activation and will tear it down on deactivation.

So, when I create a parent entity, the parent service handles those transactions.  If I create parent 1, the parent service has knowledge of parent 1, as does the db.   BUT, the child service does not have knowlege of parent1.  Also, if I have a parent1, and add a child1 to it, the child service has knowledge of the child1 that was added. BUT, if I ask the parent service to get me parent1, it doesn't see child1.

It appears the entityManagers are out of sync, but I'm at a loss for how these are supposed to be kept in sync, or is the design completely wrong?

Comment: An `EntityManagerFactory` (EMF) is what should be shared by `EntityManager` (EM) instances irrespective of what environment you run them in. This EMF has (can have) a Level 2 cache to cache instances, and also it controls access to the database. Consequently any access to connections should go through the exact same datasource, and you would have no problems in accessing things created by one EM in another. There is no such thing as "syncing" an `EntityManager`

Comment: How do you create the `EntityManager`s? Actually, in OSGi you use provided infrastructure to get a managed instance. As an  example, have a look here and expand one of the `*Dao` classes: https://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial/032-tutorial_microservice-jpa.html

Comment: Ancoron - Originally, I was creating the EM from the EMF on activation of the bundle; and using that variable for the various persistence actions.  I took a look at the example you pointed me to.  This appears to be a similar approach if I'm not mistaken.  In the example of a person with 1..N addresses, don't you hit the same issue where the L1 cache is stale either on the person or the address service?  I have changed my implementation to create a new em from the EMF for every transaction, and that appears to have resolved my issues, as I'd expect.  Just not sure its the correct way to do it.

Comment: Errh... no. If you need to manage entities that relate to each other (e.g. parent-child) they need to participate in the same transaction (JTA) and hence, in the exact same EntityManager's. Otherwise it's like putting your children in one car and yourself into another and expecting to be able to hold hands. ;-) And no, the example got a shared EM from the OSGi service, respecting the TX boundaries. JPA caches and sync is a whole topic of its own, start here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Caching and then: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/concepts/cache.htm

Comment: Simply put: use an EntityManager per model Domain. In your case: any operation involving both a `Child` and a `Parent` with a relation to each other **must** be executed using a **single** EntityManger instance. But creating a new EntityManager for each transaction is overkill I would say, since you're losing the L1 cache after every TX.